# Backbone - Call a method from my prototype view.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

so I have this view, and within it, one method I would like to be able to call in another JS file.

Here is where the method is stored (js/prototypes/view.js):

Comment: You could try creating an instance of `koreanair.View`, instead of referencing it. `var anotherView = new koreanair.View();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment above should fix your code but to answer your question, an object created by a constructor function like `new koreanair.View` has an attribute called `.__proto__` in modern browsers like Chrome and Firefox whereas the constructor function itself `koreanair.View` has an attribute called `.prototype`. Both these objects have all the top methods of your view listed. To dig deeper into available Backbone methods you'll have to travel down the prototype chain. This is pretty easy to do in Chrome by continuously viewing the `.__proto__` attribute.